# Как при выборе 3 select вызвать объект

Tags: javascript, html

имеется такой код https://codepen.io/Broanarchy/pen/rKrLXa?editors=1010 , как мне написать функцию чтобы при выборе 3 селектов Страны -> Суммы страховки  -> Кол-ва дней прибывания. Вызвать определенный объект в котором хранится коэфицент

```js
var sums = {
  def: ["Выберите сумму"],
  sng: ["500", "1000", "3000","5000","15000","30000"],
  usa: ["15000", "30000","50000"],
  eur: ["15000", "30000","50000"], 
};
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var sum = document.querySelector("#sum");
window.onload = selectCountry;
country.onchange = selectCountry;
// Выбор страны и изменение выбора суммы страховки
function selectCountry(ev){
  sum.innerHTML = "";
  var c = this.value || "def" , o;
  for(let i = 0; i < sums[c].length; i++){
    o = new Option(sums[c][i],i,false,false);
    sum.add(o);
  };
}
var europe_coefficient = {};
  europe_coefficient["15_15"] = 0.59;
  europe_coefficient["15_30"] = 0.78;
  europe_coefficient["15_50"] = 1.14;
  
  europe_coefficient["22_15"] = 0.53;
  europe_coefficient["22_30"] = 0.73;
  europe_coefficient["22_50"] = 1.04;
```

```html
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="def" selected>Выберите страну</option>
  <option value="sng">Страны СНГ</option>
  <option value="usa">Сша,Канада, Австралия, Япония, Новая Зеландия</option>
  <option value="eur">Весь мир кроме стран СНГ, США, Канада, Австралия, Япония, Новая Зеландия</option>
</select>
<select name="sum" id="sum">  </select>
 Продолжительность поездки:
        <select name="days" id="days">
          <option value="1" selected>1-15 Дней</option>
          <option value="2">16-22 Дней</option>
          <option value="3">23-31 Дней</option>
          <option value="4">32-90 Дней</option>
          <option value="5">91-180 Дней</option>
          <option value="6">181-365 Дней</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить якорь (глобальная переменная) и при каждом иземенении select, либо можно привязать обработчик к каждому отдельному select, и увеличивать при каждом изменении на 1, когда получается нужное количество, делать дальнейшие действия. Либо при выборе пункта давать родителю какой либо атрибут например change и проверять нужные select на наличие этих атрибутов!

```js
var anchor = 0;
var sums = {
  def: ["Выберите сумму"],
  sng: ["500", "1000", "3000","5000","15000","30000"],
  usa: ["15000", "30000","50000"],
  eur: ["15000", "30000","50000"], 
};
var country = document.getElementById("country");
var sum = document.querySelector("#sum");
window.onload = selectCountry;
country.onchange = selectCountry;
// Выбор страны и изменение выбора суммы страховки
function selectCountry(ev){
  sum.innerHTML = "";
  var c = this.value || "def" , o;
  for(let i = 0; i < sums[c].length; i++){
    o = new Option(sums[c][i],i,false,false);
    sum.add(o);
  };
}
var europe_coefficient = {};
  europe_coefficient["15_15"] = 0.59;
  europe_coefficient["15_30"] = 0.78;
  europe_coefficient["15_50"] = 1.14;
  
  europe_coefficient["22_15"] = 0.53;
  europe_coefficient["22_30"] = 0.73;
  europe_coefficient["22_50"] = 1.04;
  
function addToAnchor(){
 if (anchor === 3){
 console.log('уже выбрано 3 можно делать дела! ');
 }
}
  
$('select').on('change', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 anchor+=1;
 addToAnchor();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="def" disabled selected>Выберите страну</option>
  <option value="sng">Страны СНГ</option>
  <option value="usa">Сша,Канада, Австралия, Япония, Новая Зеландия</option>
  <option value="eur">Весь мир кроме стран СНГ, США, Канада, Австралия, Япония, Новая Зеландия</option>
</select>
<select name="sum" id="sum">  </select>
 Продолжительность поездки:
<select name="days" id="days">
  <option value="1" selected>1-15 Дней</option>
  <option value="2">16-22 Дней</option>
  <option value="3">23-31 Дней</option>
  <option value="4">32-90 Дней</option>
  <option value="5">91-180 Дней</option>
  <option value="6">181-365 Дней</option>
</select>
```